# How do I target the parent of a jquery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, parent

I have a table of data that operates as a time tracker. Each row is a task. By clicking a box of that row, it starts and stops a stopwatch. However, with my current setup, $(".col-6"), I select the entire column so everything changes when I want only the row to change. My plan is to target the parent of the jquery selector, something like $("this.parent() .col-6"). I believe the parent is the recordId, which operates as an Id in the DOM. What is the proper syntax for this?

Comment: you should add your html and js to question

Comment: You can use `.parent([selector ])` or `.parents([selector ])` for that. Please, next time read jQuery manual and google, before asking question.

Answer (score 0):

When you select a DOM node in javascript you can use the `parentElement` property that is afforded to all DOM nodes to access the parent element. In this case

```
$('.col-6).click(function() {
    console.log(this.parentElement.classList);
})
```

would (on click) log the class list of the parent element.